# I am having issues with invalid UTF8 byte sequences

Tags: postgresql, encoding, utf-8, ascii

I am trying to move a POSTGRESQL database from one server to another. In order to do so, I did a pg_dump and then after creating a new database on the new server, I tried to restore the pg_dumped file. For the most part, the restore was alright, but then one table did not copy over.

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] COPY failed: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x92
HINT:  This error can also happen if the byte sequence does not match the encoding expected by the server, which is controlled by "client_encoding".
```

Now, after checking database properties, it turns out that the original table was encoded in SQL_ASC2, but the new one that I created is UTF8.
I don't know anything about encoding, but isn't UTF8 backward compatible with ASC2? So, why is there an invalid byte sequence?

Would changing the new database to one that uses SQL_ASC2 fix this problem?
If I have to change the encoding of the new database, how do I do it? Can I just change it, or do I have to start from scratch and remake the entire database?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Before connecting to the database you could set client_encoding to 'LATIN9' (what it probably is; anyway: it will be accepted) You can do this by:

1) issuing pg_restore with a -f my_filename flag.

2) Edit the resulting file (there probably already is a "SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';" present near the top.)

3)  submit with "psql -U username dbname < filename".  (in most cases you'll have to supply a different username or dbname; the "\connect newdbname" is situated at the top of the script and will take over. Sometimes you even need to create a user first)

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't do exactly what you said, but when I created the backup file (for the table in question), I selected latin9, and then I restored the table. Some of the data looks a bit different, actually some of it is readable now whereas before it wasn't, though there are still some funky characters, oh well, they were there before to, just different kinds of funky.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a *nix box and your pg_dump file is plain text, then you could try running the dump file through `iconv` prior to importing it into postgres.